# Strange window resize issue in xubuntu focal

Tags: xubuntu, window, resize

I'm a seasoned Linux user and have been working with Xubuntu since 9.10.  Since upgrading to 20.04, I've found that the 'Settings' window can only be resized top/bottom and not side/side.  Has anyone run into this and if so what is the fix?

Thanks in advance,

-Ray

Comment: Is it only for the settings window or all windows? If it's only settings window, most likely that's how it's done. I haven't had a look at Xubuntu 20.04. Even if it's a bug you would probably wait for a patch. Since you're experience, I'm not asking much but in case if you want to have a look at [this](https://xubuntu.org/news/window-resizing-in-xubuntu-and-xfce). Let us know.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  It is just the settings window, definitely.  The strange part is that if I bring the cursor to the corner as if to change sizes, the cursor changes appropriately and looks like I should be able to pull down diagonally, but only the height is affected.  It's definitely not a huge deal, but a weird thing.  I'm thinking of trying straight xfce4 instead of xubuntu-desktop to see the issue remains.


Much obliged,

-Ray